# How to sum two matrices?

Tags: ruby, matrix

how to write a method that accepts two square matrices (nxn two dimensional arrays), and return the sum of the two. Both matrices being passed into the method will be of size nxn (square), containing only integers.

How to sum two matrices:
Take each cell [n][m] from the first matrix, and add it with the [n][m] cell from the second matrix. This will be cell [n][m] in the solution matrix.

like:

```
|1 2 3|
|3 2 1|
|1 1 1|
+
|2 2 1|
|3 2 3|
|1 1 3|
=
|3 4 4|
|6 4 4|
|2 2 4|



matrix_addition( [ [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1,], [1, 1, 1] ], [ [2, 2, 1], [3, 2, 3], [1, 1, 3] ] )
returns [ [3, 4, 4], [6, 4, 4], [2, 2, 4] ]
```

Comment: have you tried anything? what have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though it is possible to define method to do so, it is much easier to use ruby build in Matrix library for this:

```
require 'matrix'

m1 = Matrix[ [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1] ]
m2 = Matrix[ [2, 2, 1], [3, 2, 3], [1, 1, 3] ]

sum = m1 + m2
```

Comment: ...and `sum.to_a` to convert the `Matrix` object `sum` to an array. The arrays being added needn't be square; they simply mmust have the same number of rows and the same number of columns.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, certainly, use the `Matrix` class methods, but here is a way using recursion that might be of interest.

**Code**

```
def sum_arrays(a1, a2)
  t = a1.zip(a2)
  t.map { |e1,e2| (e1.is_a? Array) ? sum_arrays(e1,e2) : e1+e2 }
end
```

**Examples**

```
a1 = [1,2,3]
a2 = [4,5,6]
sum_arrays(a1, a2)
  #=> [5, 7, 9]

a1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5]]
a2 = [[6,7,8], [9,10]]
sum_arrays(a1, a2)
  #=> [[7, 9, 11], [13, 15]]

a1 = [[[ 1,  2,  3], [ 4,  5]],
      [[ 6,  7], [ 8,  9, 10]]] 
a2 = [[[11, 12, 13], [14, 15]],
      [[16, 17], [18, 19, 20]]]
sum_arrays(a1, a2)
 #=> [[[12, 14, 16], [18, 20]],
 #    [[22, 24], [26, 28, 30]]]
```

**Generalization**

You could make greater use of this method by passing an operator.

**Code**

```
def op_arrays(a1, a2, op)
  t = a1.zip(a2)
  t.map { |e1,e2| (e1.is_a? Array) ? op_arrays(e1,e2,op) : e1.send(op,e2) }
end
```

**Examples**

```
a1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5]]
a2 = [[6,7,8], [9,10]]

op_arrays(a1, a2, '+') #=> [[7, 9, 11], [13, 15]]
op_arrays(a1, a2, '-') #=> [[-5, -5, -5], [-5, -5]]
op_arrays(a1, a2, '*') #=> [[6, 14, 24], [36, 50]]
```

You could alternatively pass the operator as a symbol:

```
op_arrays(a1, a2, :+)
  #=> [[7, 9, 11], [13, 15]]
```

Comment: This works very well, interesting to see how you do it without #Matrix library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used ruby [Matrix class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html)?
It has #+ operator (mimic method).

Comment: As your answer adds nothing to @BroiSatse's earlier one, you should remove it [your's, not his :-)].

Comment: Well, I didn't know about his answer before. We were answering the question at about the same time. Come to think of it, I add link to the Matrix class so that the asker can study the Matrix#+ operator properly. :-)